# How to download a whole Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint

I hope someone has met this need before. I got quite a bunch of documents in a Sharepoint site. And I want to download all the docs as a whole instead of one by one. I have tried the [Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/download.htm) but it just said **HTTP 401 Unauthorized error**. Is there any way to download the whole Sharepoint document-sharing site?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have WebDav enabled,  you can just open your sharepoint site as network folder and copy paste the documents into your local hard drive.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841215

http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1603

http://insomniacgeek.com/blog/sharepoint-open-with-windows-explorer-on-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Many thanks!! I opened the Sharepoint site in my Windows Explorer and copied all the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DMS-Shuttle for SharePoint for this purpose. With one drag & drop (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ) you can download a document library or the whole site with all subsites and document libraries. You can define different filters (by modified date, size or file extension). There is a Trial Version [here](http://dms-shuttle.com/downloads/).